# Armature not following path for animation

Tags: armature, constraints, path

I'm very new to blender - i've basically made "the doughnut" and a bunch of apples. I'm doing first solo lego project and blagging my way through.

I've created an armature and mesh and animated it so it basically runs on the spot. I then thought i could get it (either armature or meshes) to follow a Path so it could actually move.

On setting it all up, a blue dashed line does follow the curve and is stuck to my armature, but the armature itself does not move.  any ideas?

Also, i kept my different meshes separate as i thought this might be useful later on. should i parent them or join them or does it not make a difference?

Any help would be great as i've just had one of those "1.5 hours of bashing my head against a wall sessions"

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=GONexlW9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GONexlW9/)

I think this should be it?  Thanks so much for having a look. I appreciate the geometry on my arms is a bit dodge (as are some other bits and bobs) but any help or advice on any of it would be great. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Press on the constraint *Animated Path* button, otherwise the object won’t move
- Put the *Offset* at 0 if you want it to begin at the beginning of the curve
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to put it at the beginning of the curve, the new world center of the object is the beginning of the curve now that it is constrained to it, so reset location will bring it to this point
- Choose *Forward Axis > X* as it is the front direction of the armature

It should work

Comment: Oh my gosh...... I knew it was something simple like that. i had Alt+A and evertying else but the Alt G seemed to do the trick. Thanks so much - such a relief after such a frustrating evening! 

Just whilst i've got you... (and feel free to ignore), i'm planning on adding rigid body to it so it can fall from the sky. Is there a benefit to joining all the meshes together or should i parent them all to one part of the body?

Comment: it's not always easy to mix animation and physics but it really depends on what is the whole animation, maybe open a new question and describe in details